# Google place details do not contain any events

Tags: google-places-api

I've working with Google places API. Here is what I am doing

1. Perform a Places Radar Search (Works good).
2. For all the returned results perform a Places Details search with the place reference (Works good too)
3. Third step is to be able to iterate over the "events" in above result and get event details via event detail api.

Now the problem is, for some reason, even in 5000 m radius I found no events returned in any place detail response.

Is this because events that are returned must be created from the calling application only? Are those not the public events at a particular place that should return with place details created by any application?

Documentation contains this:

The Google Places API includes support for events, which are defined as any type of public or private gathering, performance, or promotion that occurs at a location listed in the Places service.

> The Events service is intended to provide notice and information about
>   events that are happening currently, so that users can find or Bump
>   them. Events are included in Place Search results as soon as they are
>   added, and expire after their set duration has elapsed. **Results will
>   include events added by your application**.

I'm confused ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used Eventbrite Event Search API instead of Google Places API which worked like a charm. Seems like Google Places is not yet ready for the prime time.